# Random variable that when multiplied by a normal variable yields another normal variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let's assume that I have a Standard Normal variable $X\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$. I am looking for a variable $Y$ so that $Z=XY$ follows a normal distribution too (regardless of its mean and variance).

Which distribution should $Y$ follow in order to fulfil this requirement?

Comment: $Y\equiv c, c\not= 0$

Comment: Ok, that's fine. But I would appreciate anyway something more random :).

Comment: Maybe you should reformulate your question and ask: "... if $XY$ has normal distribution then what can be concluded about the distribution of $Y$?"

Answer (score 2):

One step above the trivial $Y\equiv c$: you can take $Y=c$ with probability $p$ and $Y=-c$ with probability $(1-p)$ (for any $c\neq 0$ and $p\in(0,1)$).

(As Gono points out, this assumes $X$ and $Y$ are independent.)

Comment: That's not true … take $Y = sgn(X)$ then $$P(Y = 1) = P(X > 0) = 0.5 = p$$ and $$P(Y = -1) = P(X < 0) = 0.5 = 1-p$$ but $Z = XY = |X|$ is not normally distributed…

Comment: Yes, true, I was assuming $Y$ had to be independent of $X$. If not, it is easy: just take $Y=Z/X$ where $Z$ is any normal variable you like ($Z$ and $X$ don't need to be independent).